Canon UFR2 printer driver Install fails on cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us at root being added to access control list
I am trying to install the most recent Canon UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V5.90. Where it fails is this below, but I don't know how to fix it.
I was running Ubuntu 20.04, but now I am running 22.04 on 64 bit. I thought upgrading would help, but it did not.
#----------------------------------------------------#
# Install Printer Driver (dpkg -i -G --force-overwrite)
#----------------------------------------------------#
Selecting previously unselected package cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us.
(Reading database ... 283879 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.90-1.03_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us (5.90-1.03) ...
Setting up cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us (5.90-1.03) ...
Restarting cups (via systemctl): cups.service.
localuser:root being added to access control list

I appreciate any help you can provide.
